# How can i set deployment options in maven weblogic plugin?

Tags: deployment, plugins, maven, weblogic

I am using maven weblogic plugin 10.3.4. I have read the goal list of weblogic plugin but it does not include the deployment option - isTestMode in the configuration tag. 
My question is how can I deploy an application in test mode using maven plugin? Would application.xml/deployment plan would do ?

Helps would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isTestMode option is deprecated and you should use AdminMode instead.  Here is an example (I use Maven profiles to define the variables for each environment):

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
      <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>

      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>ops-common-deployable-deploy</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>

      <version>10.3.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <adminurl>${weblogic.Deployer.adminurl}</adminurl>
        <user>${weblogic.Deployer.user}</user>
        <password>${weblogic.Deployer.password}</password>
        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
        <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
        <targets>${weblogic.Deployer.application.targets}</targets>
        <remote>${weblogic.Deployer.remote}</remote>
        <upload>${weblogic.Deployer.upload}</upload>
        <adminmode>false</adminmode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your reply. Although it cannot be done in deploy goal but it inspired me to stop-app after deploy. Thanks for your generous help.

Comment: What is the use case that you are trying to achieve?  Do you want to deploy in Admin mode such that you can test the application before making it available on the default listen port?

Comment: Yeah I want to do exactly you are talking about!

Comment: That is called an admin mode deployment and it should be supported with the Maven plugin and the 'adminMode' configuration parameter.  You need to enable the administration port for your servers if you haven't already.  Look at the YouTube video here for more information: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2hmxhqJLxk&feature=channel_video_title